# Is there any built-in function in python to minimize the sum of all y-deviations squared (Least-Square)?

Tags: python, linux

The task is to get datasets as well as ideal functions through csv and choose ideal functions on the basis of how they minimize the sum of all y-deviations squared (Least-Square).
I am basically confused about this task so can someone explain this to me as i m trying to learn python.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a built-in function to do that. There is an implementation [here](https://www.edureka.co/blog/least-square-regression/) that uses numpy, pandas and matplotlib.